# Update URL Snippet to Canonical Permalink URL

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls

My permalinks is in the format `domain.com/post-id/post-slug`

I notice this is a great choice for permalinks as I can share articles with a short URL like `domain.com/123`

But when I go to this short url, should it not redirect to show the full URL, becuase in the adress bar its only showing `domain.com/123`

Any setting to do to update the URL to the actual, without putting any additional load or the server.

**UPDATE**: My requirement is not to get a shortlink. Rather to convert an URL fragment to the full URL.

For eg:  If I type `domain.com/123/wrong-slug` it gets corrected to `domain.com/123/correct-slug` 
but if I type `domain.com/123` it doesn't get corrected to `domain.com/123/post-slug`

Comment: How does it currently redirect to the proper url when you use domain.com/123/wrong-slug? Do you have a [rewrite rule in .htaccess](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Long_Permalinks)? Does it redirect to the full url if you use a trailing slash? `domain.com/123`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why?

I think the reason why

```
a) domain.com/123
```

is not redirected back to

```
b) domain.com/123/post-slug
```

with the `/%post_id%/%postname%/` permalinks settings, is that the matched rule is:

```
[matched_rule] => ([0-9]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$
```

You can get that information from the global `$wp` object.

There are other useful informations in `$wp`available after the `wp` action:

### Example (post): `domain.com/123/post-slug/`

```
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [p] => 123
        [page] => 
        [name] => post-slug
    )

[query_string] => p=123&name=post-slug
[request] => 123/post-slug
[matched_rule] => ([0-9]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$
[matched_query] => p=123&name=post-slug&page=
[did_permalink] => 1
```

### Example (post): `domain.com/123/`:

```
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [p] => 123
        [page] => 
    )
[query_string] => p=123
[request] => 123
[matched_rule] => ([0-9]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$
[matched_query] => p=123&page=
[did_permalink] => 1
```

### Example (page): `domain.com/hello-world/`:

```
[query_vars] => Array
    (
        [page] => 
        [pagename] => hello-world
    )

[query_string] => pagename=hello-world
[request] => hello-world
[matched_rule] => (.?.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$
[matched_query] => pagename=hello-world&page=
[did_permalink] => 1
```

### Redirect example:

Here's an example how to redirect from **a)** to **b)** using information from the global `$wp` object:

```
add_action( 'wp', function(){
    global $wp;
    if( is_numeric( $wp->request ) && empty( $wp->query_vars['page'] ) )
    {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( absint( $wp->request ) ), 301 );
        exit();
    }
});
```

i.e. we redirect when the page query varaible is not set and the request is numeric.

ps: I just want to mention that this is using the `wp` action, that is fired rather late, but before the `template_redirect` action, allowing the redirect possible.

I also tried to come up with an example that is not using the `$_SERVER` variable ;-)

Hope this helps.

Comment: In your redirect example there's an error: you are checking for `! isset($wp->query_vars['page'])` but `$wp->query_vars['page']` is set, but it's NULL. You should add `|| empty($wp->query_vars['page'])` inside if condition.

Comment: @G.M. thanks for spotting out that oversight of mine. But I think we can just use `empty()` (some tests here on http://codepad.org/W1hGPiKY ). I updated the answer. One should keep in mind that the string `"0"` is considered empty by the `empty()` function. So instead one might use `! isset( $wp->query_vars['page'] ) || 0 === mb_strlen( $wp->query_vars['page'] )`.

Comment: Worked like a charm. So I can use it without any worry right? Like any issue may not crop up. Just wanted a confirmation from your side @birgire

Comment: Great - worked on my install as well. You should, as with any code snippet, test it well before you use it.

Answer (score 2):

The shortlink of a WordPress post is on default `domain.com/?p=30`, not the Id after the domain. If you like a permalink to the ID as shortlink for each post, then is this possible via a plugin.

The follow source is a example.

```
add_filter('get_shortlink', 'fb_custom_shortlink_filter');
function fb_custom_shortlink_filter() {
    global $post;

    return get_site_url() . '/fb/' . $post->ID;
}
```

[image]

But if you will use the page in the front end with this new short url, is a rewrite important. Below a solution for php and a enhancement in the htaccess.

Add the source in a plugin and add this to the front end or add in the theme file `index.php`. The source check the value `token` from the url. This is only possible ,if you enhance the url via mor_rewrite modul in the .htaccess, see below.

```
if ( ! empty( $_GET['token'] ) ) {
  $id = strip_tags( $_GET['token'] );
  if ( is_numeric( $id ) ) {
    header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 301 Moved Permanently' );
    header( 'Location: ' . get_site_url() . '?p=' . $id );
    exit();
  }
}

header( $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found' );
header( 'Status:404' );
die( '404 Not Found' )
```

The rewrite inside the `.htaccess`

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule   (.*) index.php?token=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest I got. It makes URLs like what you wanted work: `domain.com/123`

```
// refresh/flush permalinks in the dashboard if this is changed in any way
add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'create_post_id_url' );
function create_post_id_url( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $feed_rules = array(
        '(\d+)' => 'index.php?p='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index(1)
    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $feed_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
```

Add this anywhere (e.g. in `functions.php`), go to **Settings** > **Permalinks** and then **Save**.

---

The only *issue* with this approach is that the the user will stay on `domain.com/123` and won't be redirected to the canonical version (`domain.com/123/post-name`). It's not really much of an issue since you already have a `canonical` link in the `<head>` of the website, so it's not an issue for search engines. It could actually be considered an advantage since the user doesn't have to wait for a redirect.

---

The alternative would be just using links like `domain.com/?p=123`. They are only 3 characters longer and don't add any load on the server — they already work.

---

In the end, **why do you even *need* short urls?** Twitter automatically shortens all URLs, I do not see any need to do it nowadays, they just impair the readability of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `htaccess rule` for redirecting `domain.com/post-id` to `domain.com/post-id/post-slug`.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(\d+)$ http://domain.com/?p=$1
```

Put this rule on top of the WordPress's default rules.