# How to get better performance for redirect from domain.tld/35 to domain.tld/full-permalink?

Tags: redirect, performance

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129293) I created a function to change the shortlink from domain.tld?p=435 to domain.tld/435 and redirect domain.tld/435 to domain.tld/full-permalink:

```
function shorter_shortlink() {
  global $post;
  $shortURL = get_bloginfo('url').'/'.$post->ID;
  if(!empty($shortURL)) {
  return $shortURL;
  } else {
  return get_bloginfo('url').'/?p='.$post->ID;
  }
}
add_filter('pre_get_shortlink', 'shorter_shortlink'); 

add_action( 'wp', function(){
  global $wp;
  if( is_numeric( $wp->request ) && empty( $wp->query_vars['page'] ) )
  {
  wp_redirect( get_permalink( absint( $wp->request ) ), 301 );
  exit();
  }
});
```

While testing it seems that this approach is not the best for the performance. I wonder if there´s a better solution for this matter?

Comment: If you want better performance, then don't use shortlinks. Seriously, that's the only answer. Any redirect will be slower than no redirect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear the answer here is that redirecting will just never come with good performance. Especially doing it via PHP, because then it's handled rather late.

You could think about doing it via apache in particular the `.htaccess` file, which intercepts way earlier, before PHP/WordPress even come into play. Which will be better, but of course it still will be a redirect. But as @birgire pointed out in his [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162738/how-to-get-better-performance-for-redirect-from-domain-tld-35-to-domain-tld-full#comment235565_162739), you need the concrete/exact rules, so this isn't very practical.

Another idea, doing some javascript "magic", same [comment](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162738/how-to-get-better-performance-for-redirect-from-domain-tld-35-to-domain-tld-full#comment235565_162739).

If you ask me it's not worth it, either you redirect or you don't, just decide.

Comment: Is there an possibility to make this work through `wp_rewrite` without direct editing of `.htaccess`?

Comment: You mean like this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/129336/22534) suggests? @John

Comment: Yes, but as it´s mentioned there, this doesn´t redirect to the full permalink and just makes the post visible at domain.tld/323. @ialocin

Comment: Right, `redirect` and `rewrite` are just two different approaches and have as such their own benefits and drawbacks. @John

Comment: @john I'm not sure the proposed `RedirectMatch` will give you better performance, since the core canonical redirect is determined within the `template_redirect` hook, that's fired a little bit later than the `wp` hook I proposed. That means you would still have to travel a little bit deeper into the PHP script.

Comment: @birgire you're most likely right - I think - but redirecting and performance it's just not a good match however you approach it..

Comment: @ialocin yes I totally agree with you there ;-) PS: The only way around it (that comes to my mind) is to  auto generate the htaccess redirects with the actual slugs, maybe similar idea as with the generated sitemap.xml files, but that sounds crazy ;-) Another idea would be to use Javascript to modify the url with the correct slug, but I'm not sure where that will take us ;-)

Comment: Like `history.replaceState()` with the canonical URL, no redirect too, that could actually work quite ok, but I still think it's not worth it. And actually I like the crazy idea of generating the concrete htaccess rules just a little bit better ;) @birgire

Comment: Yes something like that. The auto generation might work for a "small number" (what ever that means in actual numbers) of slugs and pretty static web. But I agree with your answer, one should have a really good reason for using it ;-)

Comment: Sounds like, the things you do because you get payed money for them, although you have given a different advice ;) @birgire